# Какова методология работы клиента с сервером на android

Tags: java, android, сеть

Я работаю на .Net C#. Сейчас появилась необходимость мигрировать на android. И задача в написании именно клиента, так как сервер на C# написан и работает на десктопе.

На C# взаимодействие клиента с сервером выглядело достаточно логично:

```
  connect = new MyConnect(address, port);   
  ....    
  connect.Send("select ......... ;");  // SQL запрос  
  Object obj = connect.Receive();      
  ....
```

На Java коннект с сервером происходит только в отдельном потоке. Сразу вопрос: а как мне в основном потоке указать что мне надо передать на сервер и как потом получить ответ? Все примеры, которые я нагуглил, сначала пишут что-то на сервер, потом читают ответ (это все в отдельном потоке) и закрываются. А если мне, в зависимости от ответа сервера, надо отправить серверу другой запрос - надо снова открывать сокет? Вообщем, честно, пока не понимаю, как работать с сетью, не убивая на передачу и чтение половину времени и кода...
На Java я пытаюсь перейти в течении чуть больше недели, но при знакомстве с работой в сети создается впечатление, что она заточена для написания чего-то типа чатов - отправил сообщение, получил ответ, плюхнул на форму, ждем входного сообщения или своего исходящего. В моем случае - инициатором общения с сервером является только клиент: запроc клиента - ответ сервера - и все.

Вкратце, задача состоит в написании приложений для терминалов сбора данных (ТСД). Хилые возможности данных девайсов делают предпочтительной отправку запросов на сервер  и получение от него уже готовых ответов, не используя локальную базу данных.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется в вашем случае имеет смысл запустить [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) в котором уже будет открыто соединение. И общатся с сервисом по средствам [Broadcast](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html).
Таким образом вам не нужно закрывать соединение каждый раз.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте Retrofit 2 для работы с API [пруф](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).
А то что в другом потоке это нормально для Android, чтобы UI не ждал ответа сервера и не было сообщения ANR.

Comment: Retrofit - это для HTTP. Мне нужно же соединение по TCP/IP

Comment: Имеете ввиду Socket? если да, тогда Netty client посмотрите. А какой формат передачи данных используете Json или набор сырых данных?

Answer (score 1):

Почему я решил ответить на свой же вопрос? 
Во-первых, потому, что принятый мною ответ оказался достаточно тяжеловесным. Все-таки, это не та задача, как мне кажется, для решения которой надо писать отдельную службу. Тем не менее, большое спасибо **Anton111111** !
Во-вторых, потому, что многократный поиск в Google ответа так и не дал - все решения давались исключительно для общения приложения с веб-сайтами, а для работы терминала сбора данных с сервером базы данных по локальной сети не подходили. 
В конце концов, решил таки я свою проблему. Решается она посредством AsyncTask.
Вот "выжимка" из класса для открытия и закрытия соединения, и для передачи и приема данных. Если кому-то пригодится - буду рад!
Кодировка UTF_16 выбрана исключительно из-за особенностей моего внутреннего протокола - в начале каждого пакета передается количество байт в пакете. Кодировка UTF8 в моем случае не подходит.
По сути, это первый мой код, потому прошу, не судите строго :)

```
public class dbClient {
    private String chSet = "UTF_16LE";

    private Socket mSocket = null;
    private int mPort = 11963;

    public boolean isConnected = false;

    public String strSend;
    public boolean isDone = false;

    public dbClient() {}

    public void openDB(String _user, String _ip, int _port) {
        mUser = _user;
        mIP = _ip;
        mPort = _port;

        try {
            AsyncOpenConnection at = new AsyncOpenConnection();
            at.execute();
            at.get();
            isConnected = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
    close();
        }
        return;
    }

    public void send(String _str) {
        strSend = _str;
        try {
            AsyncSend at = new AsyncSend();
            at.execute();
            at.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
    close();
        }
        return;
    }

    public boolean recv() {
        boolean ret = false;
        try {
            AsyncRecv at = new AsyncRecv();
            at.execute();
            at.get();
            ret = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            close();
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public void close() {
        isConnected = false;
        try {
            AsyncCloseConnection at = new AsyncCloseConnection();
            at.execute();
            at.get();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return;
    }

    //---------------- Классы AsyncTask -----------------------
    // Класс AsyncTaskOpenConnection
    class AsyncOpenConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>     {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            isConnected = false;
            isDone = false;
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                openConnection();
                isConnected = true;
                isDone = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return isConnected;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    // Класс AsyncSend
    class AsyncSend extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            isDone = false;
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                sendData(strSend.getBytes(chSet));
                isDone = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return isDone;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    class AsyncRecv extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            isDone = false;
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                recvData();
                isDone = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return isDone;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    class AsyncCloseConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                closeConnection();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }

    public void sendData(byte[] data) throws Exception {
        if (mSocket == null || mSocket.isClosed()) {
            throw new Exception("Невозможно отправить данные. Сокет не создан или закрыт");
        }
        try {
            /* Отправка данных */
            mSocket.getOutputStream().write(data);
            mSocket.getOutputStream().flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Невозможно отправить данные: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void recvData() throws Exception {
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024 * 8];

        try {
            int cnt = mSocket.getInputStream().read(buf, 0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Невозможно считать данные: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void openConnection() throws Exception {
        closeConnection();
        try {
            mSocket = new Socket(mIP, mPort);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Exception("Невозможно создать сокет: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        if (mSocket != null && !mSocket.isClosed()) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Невозможно закрыть сокет: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            finally {
                mSocket = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```